# use of HTTP Proxy using cURL in C

Tags: c, curl, proxy

I'm working on this project that uses proxy server and curl in c and i cant find a good tutorial that teaches me how to. Can you please help me?? i need an example code that shows the use of a proxy server to connect to google.com. maybe using the CURLOPT_PROXY option.. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well all you do is your [normal curl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html) retrieval, but just set the proxy server option.

```
   curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:96666");
```

**EDIT**

```
  /* create headers */
  struct curl_slist *headers=NULL;
  headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: text/xml");

  /* pass our list of custom made headers */
  curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
```

Comment: thanx.. but what if i needed to add some extra http headers to the request before sending them??